# What are the rules for automatic Django reloading when one of the code files is changed?

Tags: python, django

I noticed that `./manage.py runserver` automatically reloads when my `views.py` file is changed. How doesthe underlying code that drives it work?

Comment: I'm not sure that there's a "rule", but since Python is an interpreted language, I think it simply detects when a file that it is executing has changed, like when you edit and save it.

Comment: What I'm interested in is how it does that (`inotify`? some interesting abstraction over it?) and how does it decide whether editing a given file should lead to reloading.

Comment: @Brobin - have you ever tried editing a python file while you're executing it? Doesn't work that way. Once a python file is running, it doesn't need the file anymore...unless you get an uncaught exception, and then you get a real fun traceback with confused line numbers.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen I was talking in a Django context. It reloads each file on every request.

Comment: @Brobin no it doesn't. The dev server operates just like a real server in that regard. Modules persist across requests, as you can easily verify by setting a global variable in one request and checking it in another.

Comment: [In the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port) it reads: "The development server automatically reloads Python code for each request, as needed."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Automatic Django Server Restart:**

Django tries to **poll file modification timestamps each second**. If it sees there are any changes. it restarts the server.

So basically, Django server checks every second the modification timestamps of every file. If it sees a change in any of them, it will trigger a server restart.

**However,** adding a new file does not trigger a restart so you will have to restart the server yourself in that scenario.

**Exception:**   If you are using `Linux` and install `pyinotify`, kernel signals will be used to autoreload the server.

As per [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port),

> If you are using `Linux` and install `pyinotify`, kernel signals will be
>   used to autoreload the server (rather than polling file modification
>   timestamps each second). This offers better scaling to large projects,
>   reduction in response time to code modification, more robust change
>   detection, and battery usage reduction.

**System Checks performed while restarting the server:**

[System check framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/checks/#system-check-framework)  is used to perform checks on Django projects.

> The system check framework is a set of static checks for validating
>   Django projects. It detects common problems and provides hints for how
>   to fix them.

When you start the server, and each time you change Python code while the server is running, the system check framework checks our entire Django project for some common errors. If any errors are found, they are printed to standard output.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work if developing using a VM using e.g. vagrant/virtualbox. Without `pyinotify`, `runserver` causes noticable extra load. However `pyinotify` on the guest cannot pick up changes on the host...